# Jquery checkbox target id's only one

Tags: jquery, checkbox, prop

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false)
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);        
        }
    });
})
showdiv();

});
```

---

The above code works awesome!! first it makes all the checkboxes "unchecked" then It makes it so only "one" checkbox can be checked at a time!

But... i need it too effect only the three checkboxes below! Not all the checkboxes on the page!!! Guess i dunno how to make it target just the id's co33, co34, co35..

```
<input name="option[13]" id="co33" value="33" checked="checked" onclick="showdiv()" type="radio"> 
<input name="option[14]" id="co34" value="34" checked="checked" onclick="showdiv()" type="radio">  
<input name="option[15]" id="co35" value="35" checked="checked" onclick="showdiv()" type="radio">
```

And then!!! ... if one of those is checked then this 4th checkbox  gets checked too!! If NONE of the three above are checked then this one isnt checked either!

```
<input id="a1" type="checkbox" onclick="showdiv()" name="add[1]">
```

Man i hope that came out right..  the html is created automatically so i cant make em all have the same id or add a class so im looking to see if i can target them by id name ..  Frankly even just being able to make the code initially posted to effect just the 3 checkboxes would be awesome.. Getting the 4th checkbox to be checked if one of the three is checked is a bonus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target them by name using attribute selectors, it's not terribly efficient but it'll work and probably work well enough. Just change all your `$('input:checkbox')`s to:

```
$('input[name="option[13]"], input[name="option[14]"], input[name="option[15]"]')
```

And at the end of the click handler (outside the if), do:

```
$('#a1').prop(
    "checked",
    $('input[name="option[13]"], input[name="option[14]"], input[name="option[15]"]')
       .is(':checked')
);
```

EDIT: Actually, I just noticed the IDs on the group of interest, it'll be quicker (and less typing) to hit those. Use the selector:

```
$('#co33, #co34, #co35')
```

Comment: Yeah!!!!! Thats what i was thinking..Just didnt know how ta do it! $('#co33, #co34, #co35')!!!! You covered all basis too!!! I just replaced the option13,14,15 with the ids and bayuum the 4th checkbox works tooo!!!!!  Tq!!

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up radios with checkboxes. You're also wrapping a DOM ready event inside a DOM ready event. Here you go:

```
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $('input:radio').prop('checked', false).filter(function(e){
        return (this.id == 'co33' ||
                this.id == 'co34' ||
                this.id == 'co35');
    }).on('click', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('input:radio').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            $('#a1').prop('checked', true);
        }        
    });
    showdiv(); 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qUtQb/

Answer (score 0):

You question is like

"But... i need it too effect only the three checkboxes below! Not all the checkboxes on the page!!! Guess i dunno how to make it target just the id's co33, co34, co35.."

```
<input name="option[13]" id="co33" value="33" checked="checked" onclick="showdiv()" type="radio"> 
<input name="option[14]" id="co34" value="34" checked="checked" onclick="showdiv()" type="radio">  
<input name="option[15]" id="co35" value="35" checked="checked" onclick="showdiv()" type="radio">
```

and you have above HTML markup now as defined in `HTML` they are radio not `checkbox`.

So try

```
$('input:radio').attr('checked', false)
$('input:radio').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('input:radio').not(this).attr('checked', false);        
    }
});
```

Comment: it is not recommended to use `attr` to change `checked` value, use `prop` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$(function(){
    var radios = $('input:radio[name^=option]').prop('checked', false)
    radios.click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('input:radio[name^=option]').not(this).prop('checked', false);        
        }

        $('#a1').prop('checked', radios.is(':checked'))
    });

    showdiv();
});
```

demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HDVUb/1/)

Comment: Thanks ill appreciate the input...I dont understand the syntax but ill play with this so i can learn, looks like for radios..  What i didnt like about radios is you cant unselect all if  you try one. Ya gotta refresh

Comment: @user2159909 Then I would recommend using `checkbox`, you can achieve the same result

Comment: Im gonna play wit this one..  i take it ^ targets all 14,15.. Thanks again